# Non existence of cyclic infinite linear algebraic groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-groups

Let $G$ be a **linear** algebraic group defined over some algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$ and also over some subfield $k\subset \mathbb{K}$. There is thus a natural group structure on the set of $k$-points of $G$. It seems impossible to me that this group is cyclic and infinite. Is this true?

EDIT: user48841 explained that this happens with elliptic curves. I am in fact interested in **linear algebraic groups**.

Comment: Interesting question. In characteristic 0, a linear group is unirational (this is due to Chevalley), so if $k$ is uncountable $G(k)$ must be very large. Even if $k$ is countable I would expect "too many" points, but I don't know how to get a proof from that.

Comment: Yes, the difficult case is when the field is infinite but countable (and I am also interested in positive characteristic by the way, but I think that this should not change the result).

Comment: "infinite cyclic" sounds a bit focused and unstable... the same question with "infinite finitely generated" would be more natural.

Comment: For my purpose, I only need cyclic, but you are right that finitely generated seems natural too.

Answer (score 10):

There are elliptic curves $E/\mathbb{Q}$ with $E(\mathbb{Q}) \simeq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the answer, which is perfect with respect to my question, but not with what I had in mind. In fact, in my case I was thinking about a linear algebraic group. What happens in this case?

Comment: Defintely $\mathbf{G}_a$ and $\mathbf{G}_m$ do not have finitely generated subgroup as its $\mathbf{Q}$-points, for get cyclicity. Is there any clue in exponential mapping ?

Comment: This was indeed the beginning of my intuition: the case of additive and multiplicative groups. But what happens if the group is more complicated? What do have in mind with "exponential mapping" ?

Answer (score 4):

We may assume, by replacing $G$ by the Zariski closure of $G(k)$, that $G(k)$ is Zariski dense. By assumption, $G(k)$ is $\mathbb Z$; hence $G$ is abelian and after replacing $G$ by the connected component of identity of $G$, we may assume that $G$ is connected. \vskip 5mm

Now a conneced abelian algebraic group is a product of ${\mathbb G}_a$ and ${\mathbb G}_m$. Hence the assumptions mean that $k$ or $k^*$ must be $\mathbb Z$; this is impossible for a subfield of $\mathbb C$.

In detail, $G$ is a product of copies of  ${\mathbb G}_a$ and copies of ${\mathbb G}_m$. Hence $G(K)$ is the product of (copies of) $K$ and $K^*$. Assume that a factor like a product of ${\mathbb G}_a$ occurs. Then $G(k)$ contains the subgroup $k\supset {\mathbb Q}$. However, $G(k)$ being $\mathbb Z$, any infinite subgroup must be $\mathbb Z$ but $\mathbb Q$ is not $\mathbb Z$.

A similar but more involved reasoning may be used to tackle the case when $G$ is a product of the multiplicative group ${\mathbb G}_m$ over $K$.

Since the questioner has asked for details, if we assume that $G$ over $K$ does not have the additive group components, then over the smaller field $k$, $G$ is isogenous to a product of ${\mathbb G}_m$ and the groups $R^1_{l/k}({\mathbb G}_m$ where $R_1$ refers to the group of norm one elements. This is a theorem due to Ono (for reference, one may see Borel-Tits). The ${\mathbb G}_m$ factor may easily be taken care of. As to the other group $R^1$, one has to work a little to say that the group of norm one elements in $l$ cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, for any char zero $l/k$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not get all details. Why is $G$ abelian if $G(k)$ is? Why "the assumptions mean that $K$ or $K^*$ must be $\mathbb{Z}$" ? A priori, I expected that we can have some forms of tori for instance. How do you deal with these?

Comment: For the first part, how about replacing $G$ with the centralizer of a generator $g$ of $G(k)$?

Comment: @Aurel: "how about replacing $G$ with the centralizer of ... $g$"  That seems like a good idea, but the centralizer need not be commutative, e.g., for $g$ in the center of $G$, the centralizer of $g$ is all of $G$.

Comment: In fact after thinking a bit, I understand now why it is abelian; it follows from the fact that $G$ was replaced with the closure of $G(k)$. The centralizer of an element is closed, so the centralizer of $G(k)$ contains $G$. Then, the intersection of all centralizers of all elements of $G$ is again closed and contains $G(k)$, so $G$ is abelian.

Comment: I still do not see how one can deduce that $K$ or $K^{*}$  has to be cyclic from the fact that $G$ is abelian. Sorry if this is easy.

Comment: @JérémyBlanc: Just to restate: first replace $G$ by the centralizer $Z_G(g)$, and then replace $Z_G(g)$ by its center $Z(Z_G(g))$, which is an Abelian algebraic group that contains $g$.

Comment: @Aakumadula:  Explicitly the issue being raised by Jeremy at the end of his first comment is that *not* every Abelian linear algebraic group over $k$ is of the form an extension of copies of $\mathbb{G}_a$ and copies of $\mathbb{G}_m$.

Comment: @Jason,thank you. All I am saying is that over $K$, the group is a product of mult and add groups (not over the smaller field $k$). The group of $k$ rational points, in case add factors are involved, cannot be $\mathbb Z$; in case only mult factors are involved, we will have to use that such a group, after multiplying by a suitable product of $R_{l/k}({\mathbb G }_m$, where $R$ iw thw Weil restriction of scalars.

Comment: Thanks for having added details. Do you use something like "there is no form of $(\mathbb{G}_a)^n$"? Which assertions on the field do you need for this? What happens for $(\mathbb{G}_a)^n\times (\mathbb{G}_m)^l$ ?

Comment: @Aakumadula: could you explain why $T(k)$ can't be infinite cyclic when $T$ is an anisotropic torus? Your argument does not seem to include this case.

Comment: @Cornulier, Any such torus maps onto a torus f the form $T'=R^1_{l/k}({\mathbb G}_m$, and contains such an anisotropic torus $T'$. We need only prove it when $T'=T$, and this is really like the case $k^*$ (with a little more work.

Comment: @Aakumadula: I guess you are trying to say that the norm map will be a homomorphism from $G(K)$ to $G(k)$, and you are trying to rule this out.  However, the group $K^*$ can, indeed, admit homomorphisms to $\mathbb{Z}$, e.g., discrete valuations of $K$ give such homomorphisms.

Comment: @Starr; No, that is not what I am doing. There is a finite kernel map from  $T'$ into the anisotropic torus $T$ and a surjection from the anisotropic torus to $R^1({\mathbb G}_m=T'$; this implies that the group of norm one elements (if we assume $G(k)=\mathbb Z$) in $l^*$ is also $\mathbb Z$ up to finite kernel and cokernel; that is impossible.

Comment: @Starr: another thing. The norm map is not like a valuation map. It rarely specializes, at the level of $L^*$ into $k^*$, as a map of $T'(k)$ onto $\mathbb Z$

Comment: @Aakumadula: It sounds to me like you do indeed have a proof, yet the rest of us do not understand it the way that you explained it.  Could you explain the proof carefully in the special case that $G_K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_{m,K}$?

Comment: Yes, I agree with Jason Starr, I still do not understand the details.

Comment: Over fields of characteristic $p$ it isn't true that the all connected abelian groups are products of copies of $G_a$ and $G_m$. You also have Witt groups. See Chapter VII, \S2 of Serre's book Algebraic Groups and Class Fields.

Answer (score 1):

[An extended comment, in community-wiki mode.] There is a closely related fact: Take $G$ to be an algebraic torus such as the multiplicative group, defined over a field $k$ which is *not* an algebraic extension of a finite field.   (The characteristic doesn't matter, but this condition does.)  Then there exists an element of infinite order in $G_k$ which generates a dense (cyclic) subgroup of $G$.

For a direct proof when $G$ is $k$-split, see Proposition 8.8 in Borel's book *Linear Algebraic Groups* (Springer, GTM 126).  He remarks also that the split assumption can be dropped, using a more delicate argument from Tits' lectures at Yale.

What I've just quoted does not exactly fit your question. since it doesn't state that $G_k$ itself is cyclic, but it does illustrate a sort of algebraic parallel to the existence of a topological generator for a compact torus.